# alert(status) in javascript always results in null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I have a php page which I want to give me dynamically result from the drop down list I am choosing. The detail regarding the choosed option is saved in the database. So, basically to get the detail from the DB dynamically when I choose an option.

First Page from where I am selecting the data (Here the data is events)

```
<form name="ParticularFest" action="" method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<tr><td><br/></td></tr>
<td><h4>Fest Name: </h4></td>
<td>
<select name="EventId" id="EventId" onchange="javascript: return ParticularValidate();"><option>Select Event</option>
<?php
$sql="Select EventName,MEventId from Tbl_Main where Status=0 and CategoryId=1";
$stmnt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmnt,SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
echo'<option value="'.$row["MEventId"].'">'.$row["EventName"].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="display"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ParticularValidate() {
  var errorMessage = null;
  var MEventId = document.ParticularFest.EventId.value
  var status = null;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //alert("firefox");
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      status = xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.ParticularFest.display.innerHTML = status;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "ParticularValidate.php?MEventId=" + MEventId, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

The next page is the one to which I am redirecting, i.e. the ParticularValidate.php

```
<?php
include_once("Db.php");
$MEID=$_REQUEST['EventID'];
$obj=new Db;
?>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<th width="200" align="center"><br/><h3><b>Program Name</b></h3></th>
<th width="340" align="center"><br/><h3><b>Name</b></h3></th>
<th width="200" align="center"><br/><h3><b>Mobile No.</b></h3></th>
<th width="200" align="center"><br/><h3><b>Email</b></h3></th>
<th width="200" align="center"><br/><h3><b>College Name</b></h3></th>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="select distinct na.ProgramName,ma.Name,ma.Mob,ma.Email,ma.CName from Tbl_Main as sa inner join Tbl_UserProgram as ra on sa.MEventId=ra.EventId inner join Tbl_UserReg as ma on ma.UserId=ra.UserId inner join Tbl_Program as na on ra.PgmId=na.ProgramId and sa.MEventId='$MEID'";
$stmnt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmnt,SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
echo
'<tr align="center">
<td>'.$row["ProgramName"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Mob"].' </td>
<td>'.$row["Email"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["CName"].'</td>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Both one are saved as .php

The data fetched from the DB (the select query) is working fine in the DB query.

Always the status is null.

I tried to see whether the status is fetching the data, whether it is mere the display part, which is the problem. But always the result to these are Null. I am a noob in these, so please throw me suggestions.

Thank You in advance.

Edit 1:
I tried to check whether this:

```
var MEventId=document.ParticularFest.EventId.value
```

is getting the MEventId, and yes it is. It is sending the MEventId too. The problem seems to be in the second php Page. I am not getting any return from that page. (I tried alert(status)  in almost everywhere in the first php page, and it shows Null popup always :D )

Edit 2:
This is done in localhost. It is a college mini project

Comment: `onchange="javascript: return ParticularValidate();"` must be `onchange="ParticularValidate();"`

Comment: Nope, it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

your alert is happening immediately, before the request finishes.

Try something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function() { makeRequest('test.html'); };

  function makeRequest(url) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```